# Side ops completed yet still available?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

Some of my side ops show as being completed, with the tick mark, yet I can do them again whereas with others once they're done, then, that;s it , they're done.

Can someone explain this?

Comment: You should be able to redo any of the side-ops, in my experience (not having tested all of them). However, I have found that some do not grey-out when you complete them? Is that what you mean?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood then. I was under the impression that side ops were a once only thing as when I'd tried to do another before I didn't have the option of selecting it, yet with others I can.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First off, any story-critical Side Op (those under the "Important" tab, and marked on the map with a yellow circle) will never be repeatable. These side ops trigger story events. Some standard Side Ops will also not be repeatable, such as those that are concerned with unique items (e.g. Blueprint Acquisition).

As for previously-done Side Ops (excluding target practices at Mother Base, which can be completed once per visit to Mother Base) showing up as available again, the game has a number of different "zones" within the same location, and each zone that you have story missions (completed or not) in or near should have one side op available at a time. When determining which side op in a zone should be available, the game *should* prioritize Important Side Ops, then any not-yet-completed side op, and if there are still no valid side ops, it will pick an already-completed side op in that zone for you to do again. The game ensures this is correct every time you are in the ACC.

Doing a side op a second time will still get you the same GMP payment (and potentially the same additional bonuses) no matter how many side ops have been done before it, unlike Story Missions (which have a 50% GMP reward penalty until you do multiple other Story Missions), so if it's an easy Side Op to do, feel free to do it and get the GMP.

Comment: fantastic answer, thank you.  The one that I repeated involved a prisoner.  Do I get duplicates?  If they're especially skilled it sounds like a farming opportunity...

Comment: Don't put too much stock into the side mission flavor text, I'm pretty sure the only thing the "especially skilled" thing means is that they're likely to have a skill, not that they're A-ranks or above.

Comment: I say that as I picked up an a+ prisoner on the 1st attempt but didn't check to see on the 2nd time. I've not had time to do the mission since.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it SideOps are only guaranteed able to be done once only.

However when you don't have any new SideOps available in an area the game will add in some of your completed SideOps back in so that you always have something to do on the map. So while you cant choose to repeat them, there is a chance it could come back up.

Answer (score -4):

The reason that some side-ops do not grey out is that although you finish the side-op, there's still collectibles in that side-op area which you need to collect but you did not when you completed it. It could be a blueprint, a cassette tape or a poster or an emblem or..., you're given this chance to redo the side-op and obtain the collectable.

Comment: This is not even true.