# How do I complete all the side-ops in metal-gear solid

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

I just completed all the side-ops in MGSV. As discussed in [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/236336/side-ops-completed-yet-still-available) post some side-ops light up again after you complete them so you can always do a side-op again even after completing all of them. However there is a challenge task, "complete all side-ops" that I would like to check off. But even though I have completed all the side-ops there is a caption in the lower right of the side-ops list that says "Completion 135/157".

**How do I finish all the side-ops?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Side-Ops completion is a bit unclear on what actions need to be completed to unlock the side ops you're missing. Since they're sorted numerically letting us know what two are still locked may help further identify the steps to unlock those.

If you can identify what side-ops are missing you can use [this webpage](https://gamingbolt.com/metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain-side-ops-guide-all-157-missions-side-op-150-and-more) to show Side-Ops with locked requirements.

Notably, many side ops are locked until completing Main Mission 46 - The Man Who Sold the World. This mission itself is locked by several side-ops and also requires the player to listen to all of Huey's interrogation tapes. These activities may what's preventing you from unlocking your missing Side-Ops

Comment: Really? Interesting! I haven't listened to those tapes at all. Thanks for the advice @PausePause, much appreciated.